# Update a field using another field from the table that has multiple values

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am trying to do update a field in the table (Table1)  using another table ( Table2). The field in the Table2 has multiple values ( example 123,324). I need to update the id for the values 123,324 which are stored in another table ( Table3).

Trying to do something like below. Since the field has multiple values, the simple update query doesn't work. Can somebody help me to write the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

update table1 set field1 = ( select id from table3 where table3.value =table2.value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server

Comment: I don't see the answer I need in the shared link:-(. Thanks for the link though!